# Task - Save & Close

Tags: apex, managed-package, tasks, saveresult

Working to smooth agent workflow by setting the tab (in salesforce) the task is open in to, "close" after the "save" button is clicked.

***Currently*** when the user clicks, "save", the tab hangs out w/out closing. We'd like to configure it so the tab within salesforce closes when the user clicks, "save" while retaining the save functionality that is already in place.

1. I have located the "TaskSaveResult.apxc" resource within the developer tools - and my assumption is that this is where the functionality attached to the "save" button lives. However, when I open it, I can't see of the code (or change it), because my understanding is that it is a part of a managed package.

Since I can't edit the managed package, can I create a class that will run the "TaskSaveResult.apxc" package, and then have an additional operation within it that just runs `window.close();` or something like that?

This image below displays the save button that I am trying to update the functionality on:

[image: The save button is on the bottom right]

Answer (score 0):

Due to the various security mechanisms in Salesforce, you can't call the class directly if it is not "global", nor can you generally get any debug logs that would useful to figuring out the problem yourself. It's also highly likely from the name that TaskSaveResult is not a logic class, but a DTO (Data Transfer Object) class meant to facilitate data transfer from the server to the client. Figuring out the actual responsible class may not be possible without contacting the managed package's support team.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, I'd like the window to close after it saves. I'm very flexible on the means, it is the end I am after. I'm a little bit of salesforce greenhorn here as you can tell. Can you help me understand where I would go within salesforce to locate what code is being "activated" when that "save" button is being triggered, so I can somehow just add a window.close() bit of code somewhere? I'm not super concerned how it is done.

Comment: @Steve I'd need a lot more information to nail down the root cause. Where is this save button? Where was the dialog or whatever that shows the save button triggered from? What error messages, if any, do you see in the Salesforce Debug Logs or the browser's Developer Console? The more information you can uncover, the better I can help you.

Comment: 1.) The save button is located within the "New Task" page. 2.) I'm not sure what you mean by this. 3.) I don't see any that is relevant to our discussion. The application is performing as expected, the issue is I don't know where to go to add the functionality of "close tab" to the save button you see depicted in that photo (in the original post.)

In addition to saving the information in relation to the tasks, I would like it to "close" the tab. As I don't know where to put the line of code to do that, there have not yet been any errors to troubleshoot.